# Qt set scroll area of a QPlainTextEdit to match that of anothers.

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

I for the life of me can't figure out how to do this.

I have two QPlainTextEdits, with word wrapping off.
I fill one using `myTextEdit->document()->setPlainText(myText);`
Now myTextEdit has a horizontal scroll bar.
Now I want my other textEdit to be able to scroll *the exact same amount* as myTextEdit, despite how many words are in it. How can i set the width within the scroll area of my other text edit to match that of myTextEdit?

I want the document widths to be the same, but myTextEdit->document()->size() has been of no use. Can anyone help?

Comment: why do u want to do this

Comment: @JosephMalicke maybe he/she is implementing yet another great text comparison software and wants two edit controls always have synchronized scrolling?

Comment: I'm loading in (a lot of) data from an SQL database, and printing it via formatted string to a PlainTextEdit in order for c/p capabilities and just general time efficiency. It could have upwards of 40000 lines, so i'd like a separate textEdit above to act as a header, and should scroll horizontally with the data so the columns stay lined up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a function (SLOT?) called when first text edit is changed:

```
myOtherTextEdit->horizontalScrollBar()->setMaximum(myFirstTextEdit->horizontalScrollBar()->maximum());
```

Comment: maybe to give up with text editor's own scroll bar (hide it) and your own to the layout?

Comment: I just did a qDebug() of myFirstTextEdit->horizontalScrollBar()->maximum and it's ouputting 0... Even though there's plenty of room to scroll

Comment: Welp, turns out I just had to do it outside of the constructor... I spent hours with the right code just in the wrong place, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, thank you for accepting my answer that wasn't actually helpful in your situation. While I intuitively feel that this may happen I curious to know all details...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using signal and slots to link the widget sizes with setFixedSize()?